# Is there a Stata function to change string variable of dates (Month/ Day/ Year/ Time) to month/date/year and numeric?

Tags: stata

I have a string variable for time that has the timestamp. For example, one entry would look like: "4/25/2022 17:26". I have over 1,000 observations. I need to categorize the dates (like time period A, time period B...). I want one category per month so I would have 25 categories (because I have data from over 2 years ago).  I thought I would first make the string variable a continuous/ numeric variable so that I can do an if...then statement, creating a new, categorical variable, where I can efficiently say if a date is within a certain range it would go to the new categorical variable for the time period.

I also know I might be planning this all wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: The question would be more focused if you explained directly what the categories would be for your desired categorical variable.

Comment: Cross=posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1661641-how-to-easily-create-categories-from-string-date-variable-month-day-year-time

Answer (score 3):

If your string variable holding the timestamp is called `date_string`, you can use `clock()` like this to create a new variable (in this example `d`)

```
gen double d = clock(date_string, "MDYhm")
format d %tc
```

That code would convert this variable:

```
           date_string  
  1.   4/25/2022 17:26  
  2.   4/26/2022 19:52  
  3.    5/17/2023 7:16
```

into a new variable `d`:

```
           date_string                    d  
  1.   4/25/2022 17:26   25apr2022 17:26:00  
  2.   4/26/2022 19:52   26apr2022 19:52:00  
  3.    5/17/2023 7:16   17may2023 07:16:00
```

Comment: ok cool! I was able to do that step. Is there a way now to categorize from there? I was thinking of creating a new variable and then doing like 
"replace new_var = 1 if d *contains "apr2022"
"replace new_var = 2 if d *contains "may2022"

I was trying "if strpos(d, "apr2022") but I've never used the "strpos" function and it's not returning what I was hoping.

Comment: Reply to comment. No, that's not going to work because `d` is now a numeric variable and there is no sense at all in which it may contain the string `"apr2022"`. If your categories are simply dates in April and May 2022, then `gen indicator = dofc(d) >= mdy(5, 1, 2022)` will be 1 if datetimes are in May 2022 (or later for that matter) and 0 if they are in April 2022 (or earlier).

Comment: It's easy to get confused about dates and times. There is no good approach to understanding that doesn't involve reading some documentation.... A key is that date-time variables that Stata wants to work with are all numeric and the fact that a suitable display format will show dates and/or times in human readable form is quite different.

Comment: I have dates for over 2 years with over 1,000 observations. In my mind, I would be making 25 if ... statements to get 25 different categories.

Comment: I don't see that `if` is needed here at all, let alone 25 applications of it. Again, please see the answer on Statalist.